# How can i specific expanded data row in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

From this document example.

> https://react-table.js.org/#/story/custom-expander-position

Result from document example :

> 1. when i click row0 data that expanded under row0 will show `Hello`
> 2. when i click row1 data that expanded under row1 will show `Hello`

about props  `SubComponent`  in `ReactTable`. when a row is expanded that will show same data every row but I want to show data that specific by rows

Result that I want to do :

> 1. when i click row0 data that expanded under row0 will show `Hello 0`
> 2. when i click row1 data that expanded under row1 will show `Hello 1`

How can I do this with `react-table` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for you Subcomponent:

```
SubComponent={(v) => <div style={{padding: '10px'}}>Hello {v.row._index}</div>}
```

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/o708980o7q

v is the element, and you get the index of the row to display. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For React table `v7.7.0` using hooks, To expand on row click follow below,

Step 1: Pass `useExpanded` to `useTable`.

Step 2: For subComponent

```
  const renderRowSubComponent = React.useCallback(
({ row }) => (
  <div style={{padding: '10px'}}>Hello {v.row.id}</div>
),
[])
```

Step 3: To make the row to expand add following to your `<tr>`

```
    <tbody>
  {rows.map((row, i) => {
        prepareRow(row)
        return (
          // Use a React.Fragment here so the table markup is still valid
          <React.Fragment {...row.getRowProps()}>
             <tr {...row.getRowProps()} onClick={() => { 
              row.toggleRowExpanded(); // toggle row expand
        }} >
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return (
                  <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                )
              })}
            </tr>
            {/*
                If the row is in an expanded state, render a row with a
                column that fills the entire length of the table.
              */}
            {row.isExpanded ? (
              <tr>
                <td colSpan={visibleColumns.length}>
                  {/*
                      Inside it, call our renderRowSubComponent function. In reality,
                      you could pass whatever you want as props to
                      a component like this, including the entire
                      table instance. But for this example, we'll just
                      pass the row
                    */}
                  {renderRowSubComponent({ row })}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ) : null}
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      })}
  </tbody>
```

Comment: This pattern works perfectly for me, Vignesh. Thank you!! 

I just wonder why an example like this isnt laid out like this in the React Table docs. It should be. I know that where I work, folks didnt use React Table, even though that's our main table library, and they went rogue by using another library—"react-data-table-component"—probably because they didnt see a way to do this with React Table. 

Brilliant, thanks!!

Comment: How to access the specific row value into the expanded section ?